# Why does the Tooltip fail on last data point when "None" is used twice?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

The following code produces a `ListPlot` correctly, except that the tooltip does not work for the last data point.

```
testData = {{.5, 1}, {.6, 1}, {None, None}, {.601, .5}, {.7, 0}, {None, None}, {.9, 0}, {1, .4}};
ListPlot[Tooltip[testData], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full]
```

If either pair of `None`s is removed, it works fine, but I would like to break the line joining the data in specific places so that the line appears as three separate segments. I could turn the list into three separate lists, but I want the plot style to be the same for each of the segments, and it would be a pain to specify this using `PlotStyle` because in practice I am plotting several data sets simultaneously, each with breaks in the same places, and I want each data set to appear with a distinct style (but the three segments within each data set should match each other).

One option that seems to work is to use `Blank` instead of `None` for *one* pair of `{None, None}`. If using it for both pairs, the same issue occurs. But then the issue appears again if I add a fourth separate segment to the same data list. So, is there a less hacky fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

testData = {
   {{.5, 1}, {.6, 1}, {None, None}, {.601, .5}, {.7, 0}, {None, 
     None}, {.9, 0}, {1, .4}},
   {{.5, .9}, {.6, .8}, {None, None}, {.601, .25}, {.7, .1}, {None, 
     None}, {.9, 0}, {1, .6}}};

testData2 = (Split[#, FreeQ[#, None] &] & /@ testData) /.
   {None, None} :> Nothing;

Show[
 MapIndexed[
  ListLinePlot[Tooltip /@ #1,
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &,
  testData2]]
```

[image]